# how to handle array of objects in fetch calls from javascript (react-native) to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, fetch

I have an array of objects similar to below in javascript

```
const userId = 3234
const filterParams = [
   { beds: 0 - 5},
   { baths: 0- 5}
 ]
```

This is the fetch call I am doing from react native

```
const res = await fetch(baseURL, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({
        userId,
        filterParams
      })
    });
```

This is how I am trying to access in PHP server

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
$user_id = $obj['userId'];
$metaValue = $obj['filterParams'];
echo $filter_params; // Nothing printing
echo $user_id; // Nothing printing
```

I have passed this in a fetch call and get it in PHP to save it in the database. But I am getting nothing printed.

Comment: VIA a restful API service? What exactly is your question? Pass it up as is.

Comment: I explained briefly my question

Comment: So add `var_dump()`s and `print_r()`s and `echo`s and `exit`s in your code. Inspect, and step through your code.

Comment: My question is am i doing it right way? var_dump printing NULL, Echo and print_r prints nothing

Comment: So `var_dump($json)`. Are you seeing your string? No. Then inspect the actual request: Go into your chrome debugger into the network tab, and check the request. Is the correct JSON string getting to the server? No. Then inspect your fetch statement. Is body the correct syntax for sending json string data to the server? ...STEP THROUGH, and debug each part of your application until you get to the source of why it's not working.

Comment: When I set  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded", then I can see the var_dump(json). How can I get that into variables in PHP

Answer (score 0):

You should serialize your data with something like [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), and the pass that data in the body of a POST request to your server. On your server you will need to de-serialize it, as you are using PHP the best way to achieve that is using [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

At this point you will be albe to access your data and save it on your db

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use the FormData class.
For example :

```
let data = new FormData();
data.append("key", value)

//Send the request to the REST API
```

Complete reference about the FormData can be found here : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/FormData